# Prevent header from getting too small

Tags: html, css, header, resize

I'm coding a Website for a friend. My problem at the moment is, that I can't prevent the Header (the part with CreepGaming) from getting too small (which means, it shrinks behind my navbar).

Do you guys have any solutions for this?

HTML: http://pastebin.com/r85DvhbD
CSS: http://pastebin.com/hyvKCxWJ

Thanks for any help!

/edit: CSS-Class with the Problem:

```
.header {
min-height: 70%;
max-width: 90%;
color: white;
background-color: #343434;
padding-left: 3%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ff8800;
border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
padding-top: 47px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You should put the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see the actual problem.

Comment: Could you add the relevant code that deals with the issue, also a fiddle or pen would help.

Comment: Sorry, was working. 

Im coding on CodePen and I dont have a clue how to post the link from CodePen here. I wasn't able to, thats why I posted it with pastebin. I think I'm trying JSFiddle.

Here's a JSFiddle link for you guys. https://jsfiddle.net/h8nnn5fc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `change` the `header` padding value. b

```
.header{padding-top: 47px;}
```

Changed it with `47px` because your value in `%` so that will be different with different screen size.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I was working, that's why it took that long to respond. It worked pretty good, it was a real "easy" mistake, I guess.